# combining two constructors that copy and move

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

Currently, one of my toy class templates has two constructors that look very similar:

```
optional(const T& x)
{
    construct(x);
}

optional(T&& x)
{
    construct(std::move(x));
}
```

Can I combine them into a single constructor template, or will this change the semantics somehow?

```
template<typename U>
optional(U&& x)
{
    construct(std::forward<U>(x));
}
```

Comment: what's the actual meat of `construct`?

Comment: @Alf: ugly placement new stuff on aligned storage :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It changes the way traits such as `std::is_constructible` and `std::is_convertible` interact with `optional`.  For example given:

```
class A {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_constructible<optional<A>, int>::value << '\n';
};
```

Your original code would print out:

```
0
```

But your new code will print out:

```
1
```

If this is undesirable, and you still want to go with your new code, you could `enable_if` it to restrict `U` to acceptable types.

The only other possible issue I see is if `T` can be a reference type (e.g. `int&`).  In that case the second constructor of your original code looks suspicious as it would be passing in an rvalue, and you might be trying to bind that rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference (can't tell for sure).  If `T` can never be a reference type, no need to worry about this.

Answer (score 5):

A templated constructor will never be (considered by the compiler to be) a copy constructor, sorry.

Comment: Erm, `optional(const T&)` is not even a copy constructor, what was I thinking? edited

Comment: @Fred: in that case, consider using C++11 constructor forwarding? if it's implemented by compiler yet. i don't know which compilers support it, if any. alternatively, if not supported, you can use an artificial base class. forward the constructor calls up to base class.

Comment: Oh, `construct` is not a constructor, it's member function template.

Comment: The IBM XL compiler implements [delegating constructors](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v111v131/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp111.aix.doc%2Flanguage_ref%2Fdelegating_ctors.html). But then, I don't know of anyone who actually uses that compiler :-)

Comment: With that perfect forwarding constructor template though, you will get problems with `optional<int> x, y(x);`. This would call the perfect-forwarding constructor template to do the copy, which is presumably not what you want. So you need some SFINAE there to disable it if `remove_reference<U>::type` is `cv optional<T>`

Answer (score 1):

> Oh, construct is not a constructor, it's member function template.

Then possibly the semantics are different. Your original overload set passes either an lvalue reference to const or an rvalue reference to non-const. The template version can pass an lvalue reference to *non*-const as well. (I'm ignoring rvalue references to const.)

In all likeliness though `construct` is either declared to accept `U&&` (else your previous overload that moves a `T` wouldn't work) and in this case *should* deal with non-const lvalues, or is declared to accept `U const&` and in this case it's harmless.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have at least `construct(const T& x)` and possibly the addition of `construct(T&& x)` defined, and your object of type `U` is convertable to an object of type `T`, I think you should be fine ...

1. A constant l-value reference of type `U` will bind to `construct(const T& x)`
2. A non-constant l-value reference of type `U` will bind to `construct(const T& x)`
3. A temporary r-value of type `U` will bind to `construct(T&& x)` or `construct(const T& x)` if the r-value reference version is not defined
4. A constant r-value reference of type `U` will bind to `construct(const T& x)`